# Can I get Schengen visa before getting UK visa if flying from UK?

Tags: visas, uk, schengen-visas, applications

I will be moving to the UK in the month of March 2020 and I will be getting my UK visa in February.

I am planning to travel to Austria (Europe) from London in the month of April 2020.  I want to apply for a Schengen visa before I apply for a UK visa. Am I eligible to get a Schengen visa before getting a UK visa since I am flying from London?

Answer (score 3):

Get the UK visa first.

A Schengen Visa can only be applied for 3 months before your trip

- assume 1st April (earliest then 2nd of January)

Your are 'getting' your UK visa in February

- when will that application be made (during which you may not have your passport)?

Since you are **moving** to the UK, that should be your priority

- which will also make getting the Schengen Visa easier and probably swifter

Answer (score 2):

When you apply for a visa, it **really helps** if your destination country believes that you will leave again. For a Japanese going to the US, or a German going to Turkey, that is not much of an issue. Relatively few Japanese are trying to overstay in the US. For a Pakistani going to the UK, the worry is greater. Other examples fall in between.

If you were an UK resident, getting a Schengen visa should be relatively easy. Few people overstay in Schengen if they could stay legally in the UK instead.

For someone who is not yet an UK resident, but who has clearly indicated that he or she wants to move into another country, it is more difficult. If the UK visa was refused, would you consider to overstay in Schengen? Perhaps not, but people might worry.

But it will come down to the rest of your application. How do your finances look? The rest of your lifestyle?